# Integrate MoPub Failover tag into Media.Net Javascript

Tags: javascript, mopub

I like to add Media.Net Network via JavaScript to MoPub. The team from Media.Net send me javascript I shoudl add to MoPub Network tab. So far so good.

They send me exactly this code:

```
//Add this code in head section

<script type="text/javascript">
    window._mNHandle = window._mNHandle || {};
    window._mNHandle.queue = window._mNHandle.queue || [];
    medianet_versionId = "3121199";
            </script>
<script src="//contextual.media.net/dmedianet.js?cid=MYCUSTOMERKEY" async="async"></script>

//Add this code in body section

<div id="BANNERKEY">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            window._mNHandle.queue.push(function () {
                window._mNDetails.loadTag("BANNERKEY", "320x50", "BANNERKEY");
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I believe both tags should go to the network tab of MoPub like this:

[image]

But here comes the question. MoPub highly recommends to [add a failover tag](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/mediation/networks/custom-networks/#failover-tag) in case the network responds with a no fill or any other error. But my knowledge is limited to add this failover tag to the Media.Net javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> loaded=true; window.location="mopub://failLoad"; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the failover tag to the catch block and it seems to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._mNHandle = window._mNHandle || {};
    window._mNHandle.queue = window._mNHandle.queue || [];
    medianet_versionId = "3121199";
        </script>
<script src="//contextual.media.net/dmedianet.js?cid=MYCUSTOMERKEY" async="async"> 
</script>

<div id="BANNERKEY">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            window._mNHandle.queue.push(function () {
                window._mNDetails.loadTag("BANNERKEY", "320x50", "BANNERKEY");
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            loaded= true;
            window.location="mopub://failLoad";
        }
    </script>
</div>
```